# Add the ability to increase width of Database Schema SEDE

Tags: feature-request, design, data-explorer, schema

At [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/new), you can increase the *height* of the Database Schema with this button:

[image]

And with the whole thing, including the area where you make your queries.  But you can't increase the width, which would help distinguish certain blurred texts (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353756/overlapping-text-in-database-schema-sede)), and make it a little easier to read.  Can we make it so you can increase the width as well as the height?

Comment: Schema: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1863/282094   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36449/282094